# Curve fit does not return expected result

Tags: curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I need a little help with my code during curve fitting some data.

I have the following data:

'''
x_data=[0.0, 0.006702200711821348, 0.012673613376102217, 0.01805805116486128, 0.02296065262674275, 0.027460615301376282,
0.03161908492177514, 0.03548425629114566, 0.03909479074665314, 0.06168416627459879, 0.06395092768264225,
0.0952415360565632, 0.0964823380829502, 0.11590819258911032, 0.11676250975220677, 0.18973251809768016,
0.1899603458289615, 0.2585011532435637, 0.2586068948029052, 0.40046782450999047, 0.40067753715444315]

y_data=[0.005278154532534359, 0.004670803439961002, 0.004188802888597246, 0.003796976494876385, 0.003472183813732432,
0.0031985782141146, 0.002964943046115825, 0.0027631157936632137, 0.0025870148284089897, 0.001713418196416643,
0.0016440241050665323, 0.0009291243501697267, 0.0009083385934116964, 0.0006374601714823219, 0.0006276132323039056,
0.00016900738921547616, 0.00016834735819595378, 7.829234957755694e-05, 7.828353274888779e-05, 0.00015519569743801753,
0.00015533437619227267]
'''

I know that the data can be fitted using the following mathematical model:

'''
def model(x,a,b,c):
return (a*b)/(b*x+1)+3*c*x**2
'''

I am trying to obtain the a,b,c coefficients of the model calibrated, so that I obtain the following result (in red is the model calibrated and in blue is the data sample):

My code to achieve the shown result in the former picture is:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DomuG.jpg)

'''
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

popt, _pcov = curve_fit(model, x_data, y_data,maxfev = 100000)

x_sample=np.linspace(0,0.5,1000)
y_sample=model(x_sample,*popt)
'''

If I plot the predicted data based on the fitted coefficients (in green) I get this result:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgLju.jpg)

for some reason I get some coefficients that produce a result I know it is wrong. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your model y=(ab)/(bx+1)+3cx**2 appears not really satisfising. Instead of the hyperbolic term an exponential term seems better according to the shape of the data. That is why the proposed model is :

y=A * exp(B * x) + C * x**2

The method to compute approximates of the parameters A,B,C is shown below :

[image]

Details of the numerical calculus :

[image]

Note :

The parabolic term appears under represented. This is because they are not enough points at large x compare to the many points at small x.

The method used above is explained in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales. The method isn't iterative and doesn't need initial "guessed" values. The accuracy is not good in case of few points, due to the numerical integration (calculus of the Sk).

If necessary, this can be improved thanks to post-treatment with non-linear regression starting from the above approximative values of the parameters;

Answer (score 0):

An even better model is made of two exponentials :

[image]

[image]